# Media query affecting non existent class

Tags: css

Short version, why am I seeing green and blue, H2s and not red and blue?

Longer version
This is probably easier if you just look at the code, but I'll explain anyway. 
I have a default H1,H2,H3 text color, blue. I have a media query that detects a browser size of more than 768 pixels (the desktop version of the site).

In the media query I set the color of the H1,H2,H3 to red. There is a class called "bar" that also has h1,h2,h3 color style, this time green.

There is a div with the class "foo". There is no div with the class "bar".

If I add a "foo" class (of yellow) inside the media query, it works as expected, if I remove the bar class, again, all good. But how is an H2 assigned to a class affecting a div that does not have the class name associated with it? Especially when  default h2 is set inside the media query. I would expect to see red and blue, not green and blue.

Can anyone explain to me why I'm seeing this behavior?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>hi</title>
    <meta name="description" content="this">
<style>
 h1,h2,h3{
     color:blue;
 }
 /*Desktop layout*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     h1,h2,h3{
         color:red;
     }

    .bar h1,h2,h3{
        color:green;
    }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foo">
    <h2>me foo</h2>
    <p>you bar  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem lies in your `.bar` selector:

```
.bar h1,h2,h3{
   color:green;
}
```

With this selector you are targeting all `<h1>` tags inside an element with `.bar` class but also all the `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags in the HTML document.

Instead you should change it to:

```
.bar h1, 
.bar h2, 
.bar h3 {
   color:green;
}
```

This will target only children from the `.bar` class.

Find out more about Combinators and Selector Lists [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Combinators_and_multiple_selectors#Combinators_and_selector_lists).

Comment: Ohhh, ok cool. Well I've been doing that wrong for years. :/ Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

You're currently only overriding the h1 and not the h2, h3.
Change your code to:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>hi</title>
    <meta name="description" content="this">
<style>
 h1,h2,h3{
     color:blue;
 }
 /*Desktop layout*/
@media (min-width: 768px) {
     h1,h2,h3{
         color:red;
     }

    .bar h1,.bar h2, .bar h3{
        color:green;
    }

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="foo">
    <h2>me foo</h2>
    <p>you bar  </p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```